# Why is my computer running slow on VMware 8 it has Ubuntu 13 running on it.?

Tags: vmware

My laptop Asus A43E with 6GB Ram, upgradable. It has VMware workstation 8 running, Win7. And I don't understand why my Ubuntu is so slow that I can't even do a task via VMware. It has wired LAN. What can I do? BackTrack OS runs great on it. Ubuntu is the one which is slow. 2048GB add for Ubuntu to run on VMware, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu's desktop environment **Unity** relies on 3D acceleration to work properly. Make sure that your hosts is configured to provide 3D acceleration to the virtual machine running Ubuntu.

If that's not possible, you could try another desktop environment like Xfce – available on Xubuntu – which does not use 3D acceleration for its rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You could be starving your pc's ram by giving the VM to much memory.

Your VM could be overloaded by trying to support the 3D graphics, I suggest installing VMware Tools.

You didn't give much info about how you set up your virtual machine, so those are just 2 possible solutions to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try some of the tips on this blog:
http://janakastechblog.blogspot.com.au/2014/08/tips-and-tricks-to-improve-your-vmware.html
Although the tests on the link are for Guests running on an Kubuntu server, some of the tips are still relevant.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.